# Get default value if the object is null in Java

Tags: java, lambda, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-client

I am curious to know how I can write a shorter version of the following code in Java.

I have the following Java class (belongs to JAX-RS):

- [javax.ws.rs.core.Response](https://github.com/neo4j/jsr311-api/blob/master/src/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.java)

I need back the int value of the responseStatus if that's possible (response is not null) otherwise default int status value needs to be returned.

I do not want to add any library dependency to my project just for this small piece of code.

**This is the code that came up in my mind first:**

```java
    private static int getDefaultStatusCodeIfNull(final Response response) {
        if (Objects.isNull(response)) {
            return Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode();
        }

        return response.getStatus();
    }
```

**The following code is maybe shorter with lambda but it is so long and hard to read:**

```java
    int status = Optional.ofNullable(response)
          .orElse(Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build()).getStatus();
```

Is there any shorter one-line way to get this int value?

Do you think the 2nd one is a better solution than the 1st?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is working.  Questions about how to improve code belong on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange,

Comment: For `String` there is `StringUtils.defaultString` from Apache Lang 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ternary operator, maybe?

```
return (response == null) ? Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode() : response.getStatus();
```

Answer (score 1):

The slightly cleaner lambda version is:

```
Optional.ofNullable(response).map(Response::getStatus).orElse(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode())
```

Though honestly, I think the ternary operator here is cleaner.

Comment: I agree about the ternary operator being cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer your first version, as using lambda sounds much like overkill.

You could also use the ternary operator, as others have already pointed out:

```java
private static int getDefaultStatusCodeIfNull(final Response response) {
    return response != null ? response.getStatus() : Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator which lets you put an if/else on one line:

```
int status = (response == null) ? Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode() : response.getStatus();
```

Comment: Additional info on the ternary operator: https://www.sitepoint.com/java-ternary-operator/

Answer (score 0):

In Java 9: `Objects.requireNonNullElse(T obj, T defaultObj)`.

Answer (score -2):

```
int status = response==null?Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode():response.getStatus();
```